# RichTextBox in .net giving weird behaviour in Windows7 but working fine in WindowsXP

Tags: richtextbox

I have an application in which view and edit of a script(which is a .txt file) has to be performed. I am using a RichTextBox on .net platform for this. When user wants to view a script, I just copy the script in my richtext box with WordWrap true. But when user has to edit it, I have to show it in a single line. This does not require the word wrap property to be true.

But this is working fine on WindowsXP but when viewed on Windows 7 PC, on editing, the script is truncated. If user clicks anywhere on the dialog box which has richtextbox, the whole script can be seen. This happens each time when user selects to Edit it.

Also, If I do a remote desktop to Windows7 PC, the script can be seen properly at once only when editscript is done.

Can someone please help in this?

Can this be graphic card issue? I have checked changing the resolution but it didn't work